# Scraping temperature, location and time then writing to csv issue

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping a Building Automation system for the temperature, time and location. I have no problem getting the information out of the iframe and to the cmd line, but getting it to a csv file i can not. Also i am hoping to put the data to columns and rows. The base code i am working with is here but i can not find anything as of yet that is similar to mine to help me. The system is also very slow to respond to requests the reason for the sleep between everything. This is only 3 of the points i started with there is about 30 i have to scrape.

This is what it is supposed to look like (cmd line):

```
Space: Lower Hall,
Temperature:  19.6 ºC,
Timestamp: 1521204222910
```

This is what i get(csv output):

```
<function data1 at 0x000001CC46775730>
<function data1 at 0x000001CC4ECA89D8>
<function data1 at 0x000001CC46775730>
```

Base Code

```
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[1])

time.sleep(5)

while True:

    time.sleep(5)

        def data1():
            element=driver.find_element_by_id("root.content.BoundLabel12") 
            print("Space: Lower Hall","\nTemperature: ", element.text)
            temperature = element.text
            when_updated=driver.find_element_by_name("_lastUpdated")
            timestamp=when_updated.get_attribute("value")
            print("Timestamp:", timestamp)
            print("") #space out on cmd line

    time.sleep(1)

        def data2():

            element=driver.find_element_by_id("root.content.BoundLabel1") 
            print("Space: Den\Bedroom 3","\nTemperature: ", element.text)
            when_updated=driver.find_element_by_name("_lastUpdated")
            timestamp=when_updated.get_attribute("value")
            print("Timestamp:", timestamp)
            print("")

    time.sleep(1)

        def data3():

            element=driver.find_element_by_id("root.content.BoundLabel33") 
            print("Space: Lower Bathroom" , "\nTemperature: ", element.text)
            date = when_updated=driver.find_element_by_name("_lastUpdated")
            timestamp=when_updated.get_attribute("value")
            print("Timestamp:", timestamp)
            print("")

    time.sleep(60)

        data = ([data1()])

        with open('writer.csv', 'a') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerows(data())

    nos=1  # Number of samples
    freq=25  # Sampling frequency
    print("\nTemperature & timestamp, sampled every", freq, "seconds:")

    while True:
    #for i in range(nos):
        ts=driver.find_element_by_name("_lastUpdated").get_attribute("value")
        #print("\nTemperature: ", element.text, "read at:", ts)
        time.sleep(freq)

    driver.switch_to_default_content()

    print ("Done.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a few of the basics of python. First of all, if you find you're writing many functions that do the same thing, you can and should just write that as one function. Second, and this is where your issue is arising, you aren't *returning any data* in your functions. It is printing out your results, as print doesn't need to be returned to work, but when you try to write those functions to a csv, since they aren't returning anything, it's just writing that function. These edits to your code address my above points:

```
time.sleep(5)

data = []

def get_data(id)
    time.sleep(1)
    element=driver.find_element_by_id(id) 
    print("Space: Lower Hall","\nTemperature: ", element.text)
    temperature = element.text
    when_updated=driver.find_element_by_name("_lastUpdated")
    timestamp=when_updated.get_attribute("value")
    print("Timestamp:", timestamp)
    print("") #space out on cmd line  
    return temperature, when_updated, timestamp      



data.append(get_data("root.content.BoundLabel12"))
data.append(get_data("root.content.BoundLabel1"))
data.append(get_data("root.content.BoundLabel33"))


time.sleep(60)


with open('writer.csv', 'a') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for d in data:
        writer.writerows(d)

nos=1  # Number of samples
freq=25  # Sampling frequency
print("\nTemperature & timestamp, sampled every", freq, "seconds:")

while True:
#for i in range(nos):
    ts=driver.find_element_by_name("_lastUpdated").get_attribute("value")
    #print("\nTemperature: ", element.text, "read at:", ts)
    time.sleep(freq)

driver.switch_to_default_content()

print ("Done.")
```

I would recommend giving this a read if you're new to python:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm